# Excel 2003 VBA - Method to duplicate this code that select and colors rows

Tags: excel, ms-access, automation, vba

so this is a fragment of a procedure that exports a dataset from access to excel

```
Dim rs As Recordset
```

Dim intMaxCol As Integer
Dim intMaxRow As Integer
Dim objxls As Excel.Application
Dim objWkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim objSht As Excel.Worksheet

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryOutput", dbOpenSnapshot)

intMaxCol = rs.Fields.Count
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveLast:    rs.MoveFirst
    intMaxRow = rs.RecordCount
    Set objxls = New Excel.Application
    objxls.Visible = True
    With objxls
        Set objWkb = .Workbooks.Add
        Set objSht = objWkb.Worksheets(1)
        With objSht
          On Error Resume Next
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(intMaxRow, intMaxCol)).CopyFromRecordset rs
            .Name = conSHT_NAME
            .Cells.WrapText = False
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Cells.RowHeight = 17
            .Cells.Select
                With Selection.Font
                    .Name = "Calibri"
                    .Size = 10
                End With

            .Rows("1:1").Select
                With Selection
                .Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End With
            .Rows("1:1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            .Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 30
            .Rows("2:2").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                .ColorIndex = 40
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                End With
             .Rows("4:4").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                .ColorIndex = 40
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                End With
             .Rows("6:6").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                .ColorIndex = 40
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                End With

              .Rows("1:1").Select
                With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End If

    Set objSht = Nothing
    Set objWkb = Nothing
    Set objxls = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set DB = Nothing

End Sub
```

see where I am looking at coloring the rows. I wanted to select and fill (with any color) every other row, kinda like some of those access reports. I can do it manually coding each and every row, but two problems: 1) its a pain 2) i don't know what the record count is before hand.

How can I make the code more efficient in this respect while incorporating the recordcount to know how many rows to "loop through"

EDIT: Another question I have is with the selection methods I am using in the module, is there a better excel syntax instead of these with selections....

```
            .Cells.Select
                With Selection.Font
                    .Name = "Calibri"
                    .Size = 10
                End With
```

is the only way i figure out how to accomplish this piece, but literally every other time I run this code, it fails. It says there is no object and points to the .font    ....every other time? is this because the code is poor, or that I am not closing the xls app in the code? if so how do i do that?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional formatting.  Here's a small piece of your code rewritten

```
      On Error Resume Next
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(intMaxRow, intMaxCol))
            .CopyFromRecordset rs
            .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, , "=MOD(ROW(),2)=1"
            With .FormatConditions(1)
                .Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End With
        End With
```

You should ask your selection question in a new question, but the answer will be: whenever you see .Select followed by With Selection, you probably don't need to select.

```
With Cells.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
End With
```

Comment: sorry....thought they were really one question about the same code. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select all range for `CopyfromRecordset`, just `Range("A1").CopyfromRecordset rs` is enought and for what i see, you could just select your data instead of all column.

```
For i = 2 to 6 Step 2
    With Range(Cells(1,i),Range(Cells(1,i)).End(xlDown)).Interior  
        .ColorIndex = 40
        .Pattern = xlSolid
    End With
Next i
```

And for the second question @DickKusleika is right.